# asp.net signalr is working on the other Database but not in my current Database

Tags: asp.net, signalr

My code is perfectly working on my 1st Database but when I switch in my 2nd Database the SignalR is not working anymore.

Comment: Hi, please contribute the error you get and any other relevant detail. Add an example or similar. You can't expect any answer with such an open question.

Comment: Hello Bojan, I'm not getting any error. My code is fine in my 1st DB but in my 2nd DB it's not working anymore

Comment: I also notice in Service Broker the request is in Queues

Comment: This is the solution I have look

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[DB_name] TO [sa];